# How to get video data/stream which play on page with javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mediarecorder

Perhaps this is an unprecedented problem, because I have searched the Internet and there seems to be no feasible solution to this problem.

I'm making a chrome extension for download video. I can inject my javascript into the video webpage on another site. I need to get the cached data or stream played in the `<video>` with this script, and then save it in blob for downloading.

I've tried `MediaSource` and `captureStream`+`MediaRecorder`, but it doesn't seem to solve my needs. Is there any other API that can realize this function?

Comment: "but it doesn't seem to solve my needs" what do you mean by that? Is it working?

Comment: Searching for extensions on GitHub that already do this might help.  Here is [one example](https://github.com/dimofte/chrome-video-downloader) of many.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Is it not working